# How can we tell that a distribution has a slightly shorter right tail than a normal distribution?

Tags: statistics

How can we tell that the distribution below has a slightly shorter right tail than a normal distribution? From what I know, the distribution below has a fatter right tail than left tail and it has a positive skew/ right skew.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you put sample quantiles on the vertical axis of a *normal* Q-Q Plot (the default orientation in R), I think that shorter than normal tail results in a tendency toward almost-horizontal
sections of the plot near the appropriate edge of the plot. It helps to have
a relatively large sample size, because there can be a lot of distracting
randomness in Q-Q Plots of small samples.

The left-hand plot below is for data from $\mathsf{Beta}(1.5,1.5)$ which has short
tails left and right. The right-hand plot is for data from a gamma distribution with shape parameter which has a relatively short left tail and a relatively
long right tail.

```
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
  x = rbeta(1000, 1.5, 1.5); qqnorm(x, pch=20)
  x = rgamma(1000, 5); qqnorm(x, pch=20)
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```

[image]